# ,"msg":"Could not resolve parent for '11' using slug (language: en)."

Tags: commercetools

Category with externalId 6 updated.
Category with externalId 2 updated.
Category with externalId 4 updated.
Category with externalId 3 updated.
Category with externalId 1 updated.
{"name":"sphere-category-sync-1.2.4","hostname":"express-impex-765d86554d-97jzw","pid":6851,"level":50,"data":{},"project_key":"arvind-demo","msg":"Could not resolve parent for '11' using slug (language: en).","time":"2023-03-21T11:41:10.152Z","v":0}

Process exited with code (1
i am not able to import sunrise category in my project

i try to change csv file but error not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay here. Have you resolved this issue?

Did you try to reimport the categories on their own?

Best regards
Brian